# Storm: Possible to set topology.message.timeout.secs much higher for one bolt

Tags: apache-storm

Part of my topology depends on working with a 3rd party API that rate limits certain calls in 15 minute windows.  Worst case the rate limit will land and the bolt will need to sleep for 15 minutes.  Unfortunately it doesn't seem like I can tell storm to "sleep" on a task for 15 minutes but I am hoping I am wrong.

Alternatively, is there a way to work around time restricted tasks like this in storm? ( have a spout feed another spout? ).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not aware of any configuration that allows you to do so and [Config](http://nathanmarz.github.io/storm/doc/backtype/storm/Config.html) isn't offering a config entry for that.

A workaround is as you suggested. When you got your output from the 3rd party API, feed that to a dedicated Spout which in turn will emit it to the 'callback' Bolt.

Comment: Spoke with most of the storm Guru's in my state and the verdict is that what I want to do is NOT possible with storm due to the intermittent 10-16 minute long delays.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to take a look at `ticktuple` (but it's only for 600 seconds)

````
```
Config conf = new Config();
conf.put(Config.TOPOLOGY_TICK_TUPLE_FREQ_SECS, 1);
```
````

So take a look at [this](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/storm-user/SddJeLLv3MU)

Comment: May have to combine the initial spout and bolt into one super spout to work around this, as far as I know a spout can block indefinitely as there's no such thing as a spout timing out.

Answer (score 1):

Might want to check `TOPOLOGY_DISRUPTOR_WAIT_STRATEGY` attribute as mentioned [here](http://nathanmarz.github.io/storm/doc/backtype/storm/Config.html#TOPOLOGY_DISRUPTOR_WAIT_STRATEGY)